# AppEngine share list of objects

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, memcached, shared-memory

I need to share across multiple App Engine instances a list of objects representing connections from client (for example an ID and some parameters).

How can I do this?

I read that Memchace works with keys and values, but what if I would like to iterate over the entire list?

Comment: It's strange to iterate over a list of connections info from client! I think it's not a use case designed for memcache, the answer of al-dann is great even if the latency is higher than memcache.

Comment: Sorry what do you mean with al-dann?

Comment: The answer below!!

Comment: Ups, didn't see sorry... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know your detailed requirements and a context, but can you consider a Firestore collection? Depending on your security and latency requirements, the Firestore might be a cheap and quick solution.

Comment: So when I need to iterate over the list (Firestore collection in this case) I can for example query for the first item matching some particular constraints. Is this right?

Comment: I think you can. It depends on a complexity of your query. Some details are here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#python and here: https://googleapis.dev/python/firestore/latest/query.html and so on.